# Multiple threads executing the same SQL query yield different timings

Tags: java, multithreading, postgresql, jdbc, concurrency

Let's be clear, i know a single database connection can be shared by multiple threads but can that connection be used simultaneously by multiple threads?
If so, what is wrong with this code? The same query yield different timings across multiple threads.

I see this pattern in my logs. The area of focus really is the timing. Thread-0 created and cached the connection to a map for reuse **(please see code below)**.
The first group of 3 threads executes the given SQL statement in approx 100 ms but the second set of 7 threads does the same in about 1 ms. The difference becomes significant as the number of calls increases.

```
Start: 1520043388189:Thread-0
Start: 1520043388190:Thread-2
Start: 1520043388191:Thread-1
2018-03-03 10:16:28,271 INFO  Connection created and hashcode: 75146484 by Thread-0
End: 1520043388291:Thread-1
End: 1520043388292:Thread-2
2018-03-03 10:16:28,292 INFO  Query timing 101ms using (Thread-2)
End: 1520043388293:Thread-0
2018-03-03 10:16:28,293 INFO  Query timing 102ms using (Thread-0)
2018-03-03 10:16:28,292 INFO  Query timing 100ms using (Thread-1)
Start: 1520043388294:Thread-3
Start: 1520043388294:Thread-4
Start: 1520043388294:Thread-5
End: 1520043388294:Thread-3
2018-03-03 10:16:28,294 INFO  Query timing 0ms using (Thread-3)
End: 1520043388296:Thread-4
2018-03-03 10:16:28,296 INFO  Query timing 2ms using (Thread-4)
Start: 1520043388297:Thread-6
End: 1520043388297:Thread-5
2018-03-03 10:16:28,297 INFO  Query timing 0ms using (Thread-5)
End: 1520043388300:Thread-6
2018-03-03 10:16:28,300 INFO  Query timing 3ms using (Thread-6)
Start: 1520043388300:Thread-7
Start: 1520043388300:Thread-8
End: 1520043388301:Thread-7
2018-03-03 10:16:28,301 INFO  Query timing 1ms using (Thread-7)
Start: 1520043388301:Thread-9
End: 1520043388302:Thread-8
2018-03-03 10:16:28,302 INFO  Query timing 1ms using (Thread-8)
End: 1520043388303:Thread-9
2018-03-03 10:16:28,303 INFO  Query timing 2ms using (Thread-9)
```

This is the code which initiates and caches the connection to a Map, it is synchronized.

```
private static final Map<String, Connection> connCache = new HashMap<>();

  public synchronized Connection initiateAndCacheConnection(final String dbName) throws SQLException {
    Connection conn = connCache.get("connect");
    if (conn != null) {
      return conn;
    } else {
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(buildDbConnection(dbName), DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
      LOG.info("Connection created and hashcode: {}", conn.hashCode());
      connCache.put("connect", conn);
      return conn;
    }
  }
```

This is the rest of the code

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


public class PlainJdbcConnection {

    IDataSource dataSource;
    volatile long queryStart, queryEnd;
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PlainJdbcConnection.class);

    public PlainJdbcConnection(IDataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public void executeQuery(Connection con, String sql) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement prepStmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        Connection conp = prepStmt.getConnection();
        ResultSet result = prepStmt.executeQuery();
    }

    private long getEpoch() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public void invokeAsynchronous(String sql, int thread) {
        final Thread[] threads = new Thread[thread];
        for (int p = 0; p < threads.length; p++) {
            threads[p] = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    queryStart = getEpoch();
                    String currThread = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                    System.out.println("Start: " + queryStart + ":" + currThread);
                    try {
                        executeQuery(dataSource.initiateAndCacheConnection("kv", currThread), sql);
                        queryEnd = getEpoch();
                        System.out.println("End: " + queryEnd + ":" + currThread);
                        LOG.info("Query timing {}ms using ({})", (queryEnd - queryStart), currThread);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            threads[p].start();
        }

        for (int p = 0; p < threads.length; p++) {
            try {
                threads[p].join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "select customer_name, customer_no, created_at,updated_at from customers limit 20";
        PlainJdbcConnection app = new PlainJdbcConnection(new DataSource());
        app.invokeAsynchronous(sql, 3);
        app.invokeAsynchronous(sql, 7);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mostly explained by the database cache mechanisms either the query or the plan of the query.

Comment: Here a good read for postgresql https://madusudanan.com/blog/understanding-postgres-caching-in-depth/

Comment: Very likely caching of plans, data, etc, and maybe the initial overhead of classloading of specific parts of the driver that weren't loaded before.